# How do I combine rows into group sets?

Tags: sqlite, group-by, grouping, sqlitestudio

I need to find the average of a set of values for customers with and without a claim statement. I have it narrowed down to the data I want but I can't seem to combine some of the data like I want to.

SELECT Motor_policies.Numclaims, ROUND(AVG(HealthDependentsAdults + DependentsKids),2) AS Dependants

FROM Health_Policies

JOIN Customer

ON customer.HealthID = Health_Policies.HealthID

JOIN Motor_Policies

ON Motor_policies.MotorID = Customer.MotorID

GROUP BY Numclaims

This gives me 4 rows - number of claims from 0-3 what

I need is one row of 0 claims and one row of claims 1-3

I tried putting: WHERE Numclaims = >1 but it returned syntax error. (I'm very new so could be in the wrong place but confident it wasn't)

If anyone can help at all I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate by a `CASE` expression which places zero claims and 1-3 claims in separate buckets

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Numclaims = 0 THEN 'no claims'
         WHEN Numclaims BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN '1-3 claims' END AS n_claims,
    ROUND(AVG(HealthDependentsAdults + DependentsKids), 2) AS Dependants
FROM Health_Policies hp
INNER JOIN Customer c
    ON c.HealthID = hp.HealthID
INNER JOIN Motor_Policies mp
    ON mp.MotorID = c.MotorID
GROUP BY n_claims;
```

Comment: Thank you! 

I see where you're going. This returns NULL in N_claims and shows a single avg of dependants but that's it. I think the CASE phrases need a tweak but I'll have a try.